# Facing name error in the set matrix zero problem of stiver sde sheet

Tags: python, function, class, nameerror

I tried solving the set matrix zero problem using brute force method, but I am facing function declaration problem probably, that's why getting a name error, can you please help me by suggesting the correct format.

Here is the problem,
Given an m x n integer matrix matrix, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0's.

Error:
NameError: name 'markrow' is not defined
markrow(i)

Code i tried,

```
class Solution:
def markrow(i):
    for j in range(m):
        if matrix[i][j]!=0:
            matrix[i][j]=-1
def markcol(j):
    for i in range(n):
        if matrix[i][j]!=0:
            matrix[i][j]=-1
def setZeroes(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    n=len(matrix)
    m=len(matrix[0])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if matrix[i][j]==0:
                markrow(i)
                markcol(j)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if matrix[i][j]==-1:
                matrix[i][j]==0    
    print(m)
```

Comment: Where are your `markrow` and `markcol` functions?

Comment: If `markrow` is a method of `Solution` (which is impossible to tell with the formatting), you can only call that method with an instance of that class. E.g. `foo = Solution(); foo.markrow(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the indentation in your code is not correct. In Python, indentation is crucial for defining the scope of functions and classes. Here's the corrected version of your code with proper indentation: `class Solution:
def markrow(self, i):
for j in range(m):
if matrix[i][j] != 0:
matrix[i][j] = -1

```
def markcol(self, j):
    for i in range(n):
        if matrix[i][j] != 0:
            matrix[i][j] = -1

def setZeroes(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    n = len(matrix)
    m = len(matrix[0])
    
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                self.markrow(i)
                self.markcol(j)
    
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if matrix[i][j] == -1:
                matrix[i][j] = 0

    print(m)
```

`In the above code, I have corrected the indentation of the markrow, markcol, and setZeroes methods to be under the class Solution. Also, I have changed the function declarations to include the self parameter since they are methods of a class.

Please note that you should replace print(m) with print(matrix) or any other desired output statement to display the updated matrix.

Additionally, make sure you have imported the List class from the typing module at the beginning of your code:`from typing import List`